# Number Systems and Compact Language

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

Hello mathematics community.

I am interested in figuring out how to express every possible number within the shortest character length using the least possible predictable "characters".

Please share your number system below with the number of predictable parts/radicals/expressions, how to use it, and an explanation to how much it can grow.

I'm going to leave this as a puzzle and a challenge for people to solve. I am interested if there are any new ideas within this field.

TL;DR and P.S. This is just something to see if there are any other systems to writing numbers rather than the base system and prime factorization. If there is anything inventive please tell.

Thanks, Aren

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: 1. When you write, "number", you mean, "positive integer", right? 2. What do you mean by "predictable"? Anyway, if there are $k$ characters available for you to use, you can't represent more than $k^n$ numbers with character length $n$.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Arence?